# optimised database architecture required

Tags: mysql, database

I want to design a database

```
on my website , a user can have multiple images assigned to it and one image can also have multiple users assigned to it.
one should be able to list how many images a user has Or how many users a image has.

there will be about 1,00,000 users and 1,00,000 images..
```

how can I built this MANY TO MANY relation between the two with minimum redundancy and maximum efficiency...
please suggest me a optimised architecture..

Answer (score 1):

In order to implement a many-to-many relationship you need a link table. 
Create a 'UserImage' table that share the primary keys of both the image and User table.

This way you can check if a user has an image, or how many users an image has without working directly on the image table.

Comment: thanks for replying but this approach is inefficient in terms of memory and access time, also it make database redundant... because a lakh-square combinations possible...

Answer (score 1):

@Tim Sparg is correct... a "Link" or "Bridge" table is what you need...  To elaborate more of his explanation...

```
ImagesTable
ImageID   integer, auto-increment
ImageOtherInfo...

UsersTable
UserID   integer, auto-increment
OtherUserInfo... 

UserImages
UserImageID integer, auto-increment
ImageID    integer -- key to image table
UserID     integer -- key to user table.
```

This way, you just need to query directly against the "UserImages" table to find things and join to the respective other to get the rest of the data...

Comment: I also thought the same approach and also built a foreign key relationship on userimage table with the other two tables(along with  cascade on delete and update) >but problem with this approach is that if we got i lakh images and i lakh users, total number of possible combinations are  lakh-square, a great figure.This directly affects database efficiency and make it redundant and heavy in terms of memory and searching time..

Comment: @Aman this *is* an efficient approach. If you doubt the efficiency of the approach then test it against an alternative approach that you have in mind

Comment: @Aman, I've been dealing with databases since '85... You have to trust sometimes... BTW, the efficiency comes in the query.  By having such a simple table of 3 integer IDs (primary unique, and corresponding other two), will be so small in the scheme of things that querying will be extremely fast even if you have 1,000 users joined to 1,000 images.  But what is the practical data showing this type of relationship (not knowing your underlying purpose of the application)

Comment: Thanks all
i was trying to find if an other alternative more efficient then this exists..

Comment: i will implement the structure u told me .. :)